# How to perform an SQL query that will return a combined data from 2 tables based on id

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have 2 tables,

- Products
- Categories

When I query SELECT * FROM categories, I get this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Shoes"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Electronics"
    }
]
```

And when I query SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 1, I get this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "PlayStation 4",
    "image": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSr-iFW5W8n3_jxNKiclAP_k71Fi9PGcojsMUC-vb8zbwJthbBd",
    "images": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSr-iFW5W8n3_jxNKiclAP_k71Fi9PGcojsMUC-vb8zbwJthbBd;https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-56933980,width-640,resizemode-4,imgsize-85436/56933980.jpg;https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/3328be45e8c7fe5194055b4c687fb769-1200-80.jpeg;https://img.etimg.com/thumb/width-640,height-480,imgsize-76492,resizemode-1,msid-52464286/46.jpg",
    "description": "With PS4, gaming becomes a lot more power packed. Ultra-fast processors, high-performance system, real-time game sharing, remote play and lots more makes it the ultimate companion device.",
    "price": 240.99,
    "quantity": 0,
    "short_desc": "Gaming console",
    "cat_id": 2
}
```

I want to write a query that will return me the product with the added key of "category" instead of "cat_id" so after I write the query and get back a product I will get something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "PlayStation 4",
    "image": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSr-iFW5W8n3_jxNKiclAP_k71Fi9PGcojsMUC-vb8zbwJthbBd",
    "images": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSr-iFW5W8n3_jxNKiclAP_k71Fi9PGcojsMUC-vb8zbwJthbBd;https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-56933980,width-640,resizemode-4,imgsize-85436/56933980.jpg;https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/3328be45e8c7fe5194055b4c687fb769-1200-80.jpeg;https://img.etimg.com/thumb/width-640,height-480,imgsize-76492,resizemode-1,msid-52464286/46.jpg",
    "description": "With PS4, gaming becomes a lot more power packed. Ultra-fast processors, high-performance system, real-time game sharing, remote play and lots more makes it the ultimate companion device.",
    "price": 240.99,
    "quantity": 0,
    "short_desc": "Gaming console",
    "category": "Electronics"
}
```

basically, what's matching in the product "cat_id" in the categories table so cat_id == id (from categories table). Appreciate all the help I can get :)

Comment: See about joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.image, p.images, p.description, p.price, p.quantity, p.short_desc,
c.title as category FROM products p JOIN categories c ON
    c.id = p.cat_id;
```

Comment: Worked! thanks a lot, appreciate the help and there was just a small typo in your answer in 'p.,image', just removed the ',' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to select the * for the products table and title as category from the categories table with the join on the primary key in your case which is Id.